# can't run remote ssh command without heredoc

Tags: ssh, bash

I can't get this command to work:

```
user@server:~: ssh otherserver bash -ic 'source .profile; some-aliased-command'
```

Variations I tried

```
user@server:~: ssh -t otherserver bash -ic 'source .profile; some-aliased-command'
user@server:~: ssh -t otherserver "bash -ic 'source .profile; some-aliased-command'"
user@server:~: ssh -t otherserver "bash -ic source .profile; some-aliased-command"
user@server:~: ssh otherserver bash -ic 'source .profile; some-aliased-command'
user@server:~: ssh otherserver "bash -ic 'source .profile; some-aliased-command'"
user@server:~: ssh otherserver "bash -ic source .profile; some-aliased-command"
```

I usually get a variation of these errors:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument
bash:  no job control in this shell
stdin: is not a tty
bash: some-aliased-command: command not found
```

But like this, it does work:

```
user@server:~: ssh otherserver bash -i << EOF
source .profile
some-aliased-command
EOF
```

In fact when I run this:

```
ssh -t otherserver 'bash -ic "source ~/.profile; alias"'
```

It lists all the aliases including the `some-aliased-command` that I want to run.

I tried al sorts of variations with single, double, escaped quoutes, but I am stuck and it will only work with the heredoc version.

How do I make it work without the heredoc ( as a one-liner ) ?

Comment: Maybe `.profile` contains commands that require a tty. Why are you sourcing `.profile` in the first place?

Comment: @kasperd Because I need an alias that is in there. The .profile and .bashrc files are not under my control. I can edit them, but they could be reset at any time.

Comment: Aliases do not belong in `.profile`. Aliases are local to the shell and `.profile` is only sourced by login shells. So most shells would not have any access to those aliases. If you have aliases in `.profile`, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @kasperd Then why does it work when I do `ssh -t otherserver 'bash -ic "source ~/.profile; alias"'` or use the heredoc syntax ? How is it different ?

Comment: We might be able to figure out why that convoluted command makes a difference. But I would say it is pointless. Put the aliases where they belong, then there will be fewer unknowns to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as previous, but add `+m` for job control issue fix:

```
ssh otherserver "bash -ic +m 'source .profile; some-aliased-command'"
```